# Put condition on ng-submit in multiple row item

Tags: angularjs

I am working on Angualrjs.below is my code

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="OnClickSubmit())">
 <div  ng-repeat="ReadItem in SelectedItem" >

<label class="input">
<input type="text" id="txt_{{ReadItem.No}}" ng-model="ReadItem.Quantity" name="Quantity" required  />
<div ng-show="myForm.Quantity.$dirty && myForm.Quantity.$error.required" class="note field-error">Required!</div>
<div ng-show="(myForm.Quantity.$dirty && ((5 < ReadItem.Quantity))" class="note field-error">Qty More.</div>
</label>   
</div>
<button >order</button>
</form>
```

i wanted to perform validation on condition only when i click  single button order.button is placed bottom of page.it's not added on every row.

1.my form is valid, i mean all field is not empty.

2.and quantity should not grater than 5.
please let me know how to achieve this functionality on multiple row item.

if any condition fail then OnClickSubmit() should not fired.

Comment: Always do validation in the final step, `OnClickSubmit`. You can read the values using the scope variables bound to `ng-model`. If it's invalid, prevent it submitting at point of execution, it is the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, `ng-disabled` and `$invalid` would be your bestfriend:

```
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
```

This will disable your `button` until all fields required is valid.